# What is the testing setup of NodeJS Mobile App Service (Azure Based) for Xamarin Mobile Apps?

Tags: c#, node.js, xamarin, tdd, azure-mobile-services

The current documentation gives no guide on testing the app service backend. What are the tools or setup needed for unit testing a Xamarin Mobile App Service (based on Nodejs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways to answer this.

Firstly, let's talk about the table controllers.  These can be "imported" and the functions tested with a mock service.  Just supply a mock context with an execute() method on it.  You may find this useful: http://tobyho.com/2015/12/16/mocha-with-promises/ - remember that the table controller methods return promises.

Next, let's talk about the APIs.  You can build up your entire environment and then use Supertest to test the API: https://www.codementor.io/nodejs/tutorial/testing-express-apis-with-supertest

A great source of tests are the tests that are supplied with the node SDK.  They can give you great information about how we test the Node SDK before it is released.

Comment: I tried testing the APIs, but it keeps using the api path as inside the mocha/bin/ folder.

Comment: That sounds like you are not using Supertest properly.  Supertest goes against the actual Express server.